# Django template won't render photos

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to render photos from my static file, but it does not work. The path is found, but the photos will not render. Here is part of my code:

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    adultcontent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    book_photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def bookIndex(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()

    form = BookForm()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/books')
        

    context = {'books': books, 'form':form}
    return render(request, '../templates/list.html', context)
```

template: (if i make it {{book.book_photo.url}} it crashes

```
{% load static %}


{% for book in books %}
{% if book.adultcontent == True and user.is_child %}
<div class="hidden">
    {% if user.is_admin%}
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'edit_book' book.id %}">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_book' book.id %}">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
<div class="book-row">
    {% if user.is_admin%}
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'edit_book' book.id %}">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_book' book.id %}">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
    
    
            <span></span>
            
            <span>{{book}}</span>
            <img class="photo" src="{{book.book_photo}}" >
        
            
            
            {% endif %}
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

I have additionaly configured settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT =    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

and have added `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

the console shows that the source of the photo is found but the images appear broken:

[image: Console photo]

I have tried everything to make it work. Does anyone have any ideas where I might be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get when you use book.book_photo.url?

Comment: I get:
ValueError at /books/
The 'book_photo' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: are you putting your files in a media folder? Also it shouldn't crash if its not finding an image, it would just not render the image....So something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Install pillow, the image library with this command:

"pip install pillow"

and try again. It should work.

Comment: Pillow is installed

Comment: Replace the image source with this:     src="{{book.book_photo.url}}".        Add  ".url" after the "book.book_photo".

Comment: Also, note that whitespaces can affect your code. Look at the MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py file (Delete the unnecessary spaces).

Comment: sadly that breaks the page and I get: ValueError at /books/ The 'book_photo' attribute has no file associated with it

Comment: Could you show me your file structure? That would really help in solving this once and for all.

Comment: I would need to see the file structure. That way, I can know if you are pointing in the right direction, at least.

Comment: @NewDeveloper Resolved yet?

Comment: Also, change this in your views.py, '../templates/list.html' to simply 'list.html'. Django already knows it should look in the templates folder. And again, go into your settings.py file and add this within the [ ] after the DIRS within the "TEMPLATES" dictionary. Like this, "BASE_DIR / 'templates'". i.e. 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']

Comment: Hey Maximilian, thank you for your effort to help me! I have not been able to solve the issue but I will get back to you soon with the project structure. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @NewDeveloper You're welcome.

Comment: @NewDeveloper, you could tell me how you solved it; if you don't mind, of course.

Comment: Hi Maximilian, sorry for the late response. I did not solve it sadly. It was for an exercise and the dealine is over, so I have moved on to other projects. 

I do however think that the problem was in definding the directories. I think that the structure of my apps and my project was a bit weird so django could not serve properlt acess the right URL. So I thinki you were on to something when you asked for my project structure!

Comment: No worries @NewDeveloper